# Error while executing the command

Tags: command-line

By the way I am trying to run my script, when my '8443' port is not listen. For that I wrote a command like below in my command prompt,

```
if [ ! ps aux | grep '[8]443' | awk '{print $2}'] ]; then sh boot.sh; fi
```

This gave me error like below.

```
awk: {print $2}]
awk:           ^ syntax error
bash: [: missing `]'
```

How to write this with correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird syntax you are using.

If I understand the code, you are doing `ps aux` and, in case there is no line with the code `8443` on the second column, you want to run the script `boot.sh`.

You can instead use something like:

```
if [ -z "$(ps aux | awk '$2==8443')" ]; then
    sh boot.sh
fi
```

`-z` means: "the length of STRING is zero". So this checks the output of `ps aux` with `awk` by checking if there is any 2nd column with `8443` as value. In this case there will be some output, so `-z` will be false and the command won't be executed. But if there is no output, `-z` will be true and `boot.sh` will be executed.

Your approach was failing because you were doing:

```
if [ ! .... ] ];
```

which neither executes a command properly and checks its output neither is correct: you have one `]` too many.

Comment: here -z means?@fedorqui

Comment: "The length of string is zero", meaning there is no output. I had also added to the answer. You can test it by doing `[ -z "" ] && echo "yes"` and `[ -z "a" ] && echo "yes"`.

Comment: ps aux | awk '/8443/ {print $2}'
     when i try this it shows me one pid. But there is no process running on port 8443

Comment: if [ -z "$(ps aux | awk '/[8]443/ {print $2}')" ]; then
    sh boot.sh
fi     Shal i use your comment like this? It reject the process id which was shown by condition

Comment: @VijayVishnu Aaah so you want to check if `8443` is in the second column. Then just use: `if [ -z "$(ps aux | awk '$2==8443')" ]; then` ...

Comment: @VijayVishnu If you want to perform an action **if** the digit does **not** appear in the 2nd column of `ps aux` output, then use: `if [ -z "$(...)" ]`. If you want to do something **if** the digit **appears**, then negate it: `if [ ! -z "$(...)" ]`.

Comment: by using ur comment the condition will always be true..It execute the script boot.sh always..

Comment: @VijayVishnu What command are you using? If you do not properly what you are doing exactly, I cannot help you. And we've been posting many comments for such a simple question. Read again my comments and do a proper test.

Comment: ps aux | awk '/8443/ {print $2}'  why this command will always show one pid(digits)?

Comment: @VijayVishnu Because it does check the output of `ps aux` by printing the second column is the line contains `8443`. But the command I suggested is `ps aux | awk '$2==8443'`: this will return the line containing 8443 as 2nd column; otherwise, nothing. Isn't this what you want to do??????

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
TMPVAR=`ps aux | grep '[8]443' | awk '{print $2}'` if [ "$TMPVAR" != "" ] ; then sh boot.sh ; fi
```

Comment: this is overkilling. `grep '[8]` makes `grep -v grep` unnecessary

Comment: you are right. fixed it. still not as good as your answer but better than it was

Comment: still there is no need to `export`.